# Where is my reasoning wrong?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

We know that components of locally connected sets are open. Now consider the space
$$X=\bigcup\limits_{q \in \mathbb{Q}}^{} \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2; x^2+y^2=q^2 \}-\{(0,0) \}$$
Now this seems locally connected, since every point belongs to a circle and you can just take smaller and smaller arcs around that point. However the components are the circles $x^2+y^2=q^2$ which aren't open.
Edit: $q \in \mathbb{Q}^{+}$ not $q \in \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Why write an edit as a remark. Just edit. Also, you have 150 characters for the title space, how about a more descriptive title perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not locally connected at all: any point on the circle has basic neighbourhoods that are intersection of open balls in the plane with $X$, and these will contain many points from other rational-radius circles. So your arcs aren’t neighbourhoods at all.

You treat the circles like they’re a topological sum, not as a subspace of the plane.

Comment: Oh yeah, forgot the neighborhood basis elements need to be open. Thanks!

Comment: @InsertNameHere they need to contain an open set, yes, but neighbourhoods need not be open.